# Julia Excel Object

Tags: excel, object, julia

In **MATLAB** someone can write to excel and format excel sheets by creating an **Excel object** using the actxserver command and then using vba-like commands: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-a-matlab-application-as-an-automation-client.html

Does **JULIA** provide a similar functionality?

Comment: Does Julia have vba type commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Use a Julia native library (`XLSX.jl`) *<== RECOMMENDED*
2. Use some of available Python libraries via `PyCall.jl` (works as charm as well) - among those options VBA-like command option is available as well - see code at the end of this post

Ad.1.

Writing a spreadsheet

```
using XLSX
using Dates
XLSX.openxlsx("smyample.xlsx", mode="w") do xf
    sheet = xf[1]
    XLSX.rename!(sheet, "NewSheetName")
    sheet["A1"] = "Data generated on:"
    sheet["B1"] =  Dates.now()
    dat = rand(4, 5)
    for i in 1:size(dat,1), j in 1:size(dat,2)
        XLSX.setdata!(sheet, XLSX.CellRef(2+i, j), dat[i,j])
    end
end
```

Reading a spreadsheet:

```
julia> wb = XLSX.readxlsx("mysample.xlsx")
XLSXFile("sample2.xlsx") containing 1 Worksheet
            sheetname size          range
-------------------------------------------------
         NewSheetName 6x5           A1:E6
```

Let's get first two columns:

```
julia> XLSX.getcellrange(ws, ws.dimension)[:,1:2]
6×2 Array{XLSX.AbstractCell,2}:
 Cell(A1, "s", "", "0", "")                   Cell(B1, "", "1", "43995.77937614583", "")
 EmptyCell(A2)                                EmptyCell(B2)
 Cell(A3, "", "", "0.7723129181734945", "")   Cell(B3, "", "", "0.9539233196840988", "")
 Cell(A4, "", "", "0.15112461473849814", "")  Cell(B4, "", "", "0.9088105399888486", "")
 Cell(A5, "", "", "0.38606711950516326", "")  Cell(B5, "", "", "0.274487313772527", "")
 Cell(A6, "", "", "0.4390332370925689", "")   Cell(B6, "", "", "0.04038483579623442", "")
```

a `Cell` object has a field `value` so you can further process it.

You can also simply ask for any cell as well:

```
julia> ws["A1"], ws["B1"]
("Data generated on:", DateTime("2020-06-13T18:42:18"))
```

Perhaps usually you will prefer a high-level `DataFrames`-oriented API:

```
using XLSX
using DataFrames
df1 = DataFrame(a=1:3, b=6:8);
df2 = DataFrame(x1=1:3, x2=string.('A':'C'));


XLSX.writetable("myexcel.xlsx",
    MySheetName1=(collect(eachcol(df1)), names(df2)),
    MySheetName2=(collect(eachcol(df2)), names(df2)))
```

Ad.2.

Start by installing `openpyxl`:

```
using Conda
Conda.add("openpyxl")
```

And then any Python example will work, e.g.:

```
using PyCall
xl = pyimport("openpyxl")

wb = xl.Workbook();
ws = wb.active

ws["A1"] = "hello world"

wb.save("yetanother.xlsx")
```

Last but not least, you can automate Excel via ActiveX. For most case scenarios I do not recommend it (speed, non cross-platform, requires Office installed, requires desktop environment etc.) but here it is:

```
using Conda
Conda.add("pywin32")

using PyCall
pw = pyimport("win32com")
pwc = pyimport("win32com.client")
import win32com.client

xlApp = pwc.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible=1
workBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\temp\\MyTest.xlsx")
workBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "hello world"
workBook.Close(SaveChanges=1) 
xlApp.Quit()
```

Comment: To note that this answer only a subset of the issues asked by the op..

Comment: I added ActiveX example however I understood that the goal is to read and write Excel files. Doing this through ActiveX has many caveats when used in production... anyway it made to the list of my examples.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! So, there are several ways to read/write data. However the only way to format an excel sheet (e.g. increase the font size of a cell, change the color of a cell range etc.) is using Conda via ActiveX. Would you confirm that?

Comment: Definitely not! Almost the only case when I can imagine someone would be so desperate to use ActiveX is running VBA macros. Otherwise do not touch it.  `XLSX.jl` has several `XLSX.styles*`  methods and here is styles docs for openpyxl https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html

Comment: Good to know and thanks for the further clarifications!